# How to see the build version of a build project with npm

Tags: npm, webpack, vue.js, build

I know that my question gonna be quite stupid for the pro vue.js and Webpack. I'm not really use to it yet.

I have actually a little application with vue.js and webpack. I was developing and seeing the result by using the command : npm run dev
and looking at the local adress : http://localhost:8080/

Then, I have done a build version with : npm run build
So eveything is fine but now, I dont know how to see the final result locally. What I have to do or what I'm missing ?

Thank for your answer

Comment: The question is kind of confusing to me, but usually I use `npm start` to run my application

Comment: But "npm start" seems to also run the dev version. I'm trying to see the result of the build version, the one with all the file minified

Comment: cd into build folder which is created, and then start?

Comment: Even if I go I start the comand "npm start" from within the folder. As soon as I start the command, it runs the dev version and come back the previous folder

Comment: Maybe my question is more about how to create a HTTP server for running the builded version like we do for the dev version

Comment: Ah, you needed a http server.  I usually just use a python script: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` but you can easily leverage an NPM variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `http-server` npm package:

```
yarn global install http-server

# Or

npm install -g http-server
```

then `cd` into your built folder and launch `http-server`. This should give you a url to go to.